# Insert new row with max value incremented by simple computation (concurrency issue)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

In my java/spring/hibernate application I need to generate invoice numbers in format `yyxxxxxxxx` (yy - current year, xxxxxxxx - number sequence starting from 1 each year, 10 digits in total.)

For example, first number next year will be 1800000001.

I use Oracle 11g express edition. The application runs simultaneously on 2 Tomcat servers.

I'm not sure how to handle possible duplicates - or rather unique constraint violations, since there is unique constraint on `InvoiceNumber` column. (There are 3 columns in `GeneratedInvoiceNumbers` table - `ID`(PK, auto incremented), `InvoiceNumber`, `CreatedOn`.)

So far the app retrieves row with `max(ID)`, generates a new invoice number and inserts a new row. Since multiple threads/servers may select the same `max(ID)` and therefore generate/insert the same invoice number, the application catches Spring `DataIntegrityViolationException` thrown, increments the invoice number and keeps trying to insert it until it succeeds (with some `max_attempts_limit` set). It works but does not seem as a clean solution.

I thought of putting the invoice number generation logic into a stored procedure - it should be possible to put a lock on it and allow only one execution at the time. But then I would have to deal with a different exception which would get me where I am now.

Is there a better way to solve this?

EDIT: Although essentially I don't really care for each generated number individually. I just need to know the max invoice number each year to generate the next. I could just make the structure like this:

```
ID, Year, LastNumber
```

and do `INSERT` if the current year row does not yet exist, else `UPDATE` with incremented LastNumber - which seems easier to do in concurrent environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use max(id), create oracle sequence and get next value from sequence - `select nextval`. This is the most reliable and less error-prone approach. Even if you have 1 application you would have a race when multiple threads trying to get max(id) from the database

Alternatively you can use something like below for 1 node:

```
synchonized (lock) {
   long id = selectMaxFromDatabase(id);
   id ++;
   if (id % 2 != 0) {
      id ++;
   }  
}
```

For second node:

```
synchonized (lock) {
   long id = selectMaxFromDatabase(id);
   id ++;
   if (id % 2 == 0) {
      id ++;
   }  
}
```

One application will insert odd ids, the second one even ids.

Comment: I would like to avoid using different application code on different nodes if possible. And I need to start from 00000001 each year. If I understand it correctly, it means to reset the sequence..

Comment: Well you can use just different configuration files for different nodes but same application code.

Comment: I decided to add a `Year` column, create a sequence and reset it each year.

Comment: @lfo Rather ugly approach to reset sequence every year, once a year you will have a bug because something bad will happen. Even better to catch DataIntegrityViolationException and repeate insert.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the problem, should be.

This is a concurrency problem, where two applications may try to write simultaneously on you table. Therefore, can you make on application start writing form the range `0-5.0000.0000`, and the other from `10.0000.0000-5.000.0000`. Moreover you would not need to care about they writing the same number as `00.0000.0001`, because they do it from different places, then you will not end up overriding/losing primary keys because of the concurrency problem.

Comment: Not really. Current max invoice number may be 1700000001 and I need the next one to be 1700000002 no matter in which application. It may not be clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to use a sequence, and let the database handle it. Easy to implement, less error prone (as stated by Anton)